# VBA: How to Pull Mid String 2 Character State From Address?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am looking for the best way to go about manipulating this string: We need to extract a state from the invoice line description field of my Excel. Here is an example of the type of line I need to extract the state from:

```
Managment Blvd.Philadelphia.PA.19103
Management EXECUTIVE CTJACKSONVILLE.FL.32216-4041
```

So as you can see, the state code is immediately after the zip code from the right side. Here is what I am thinking:

```
IF(isnumeric(Right(mystring,5)) 

Then 
MyString = Right(mystring,8)
MyString =Left(mystring,2)

End If
```

Would that give me the 2 characters for the state? Or is there a much better way to do this? Maybe even add some checks by adding a table of state abbreviations to compare the characters to make sure they match a state.

Currently however, I do not know what to do for Zip codes that include the +4 like in the 2nd example. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is there ever any other numbers in the string besides the zip code?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Since this is programming for a wide database of addresses' - many will have other numbers for the house#, Suite#, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming state is always the second last

```
 Function getState(description As String) As String
     Dim s() As String
     s = Split(description, ".")
     getState = s(UBound(s) - 1)
 End Function
```

If state could be anywhere in string but is always 2 letters and closer to end of string then

```
 Function getState(description As String) As String
     Dim i As Long
     Dim s() As String
     s = Split(description, ".")
     For i = UBound(s) To LBound(s) Step -1
         If Len(s(i)) = 2 Then
             getState = s(i)
             Exit For
         End If
     Next
 End Function
```

Comment: I'm liking your first suggestion if that works - the period is a good place to grab it from since regardless of it being a 5 digit or 9 digit zip code it is always after the period. My only concern now are strings that don't actually have the state. Is the best option after that simply to compare the 2 digit state string to an actual list of states to make sure those 2 chars match a state?

Comment: The amount of checking really comes down to how much you need the state to be there and how much variance can be in the string e.g. what if someone types in Florida instead of FL etc.  But if it'll always be a 2 letter code then checking against a list is solid.

Comment: Ok - so I'm trying to implement this into my database as far as importing in into my Access Table. How can I get this into my table so that it calculates this within my select statement for each description?

Comment: Are the description strings already in a table?  If they are you can just do a UPDATE query with the above function (or Append if you want to put it into a new table).  Will need more specifics to be able to help.

Comment: Description strings are already in the table. So sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to calling a VBA function in the middle of a SQL query. How would I go about calling the function while doing a SQL query to read the Access table? Something along the lines of this?

UPDATE description SET description = getState(table.description)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the string and do an InStr for the period between the state and the zip.

Here's an example of a function to reverse a string:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'Define Variables

Dim Original_String As String
Dim Reversed_String As String
Dim Next_Char As String

Dim Length As Integer
Dim Pos As Integer

'Get the Original String

Original_String = InputBox("Pls enter the original string: ")

'Find the revised length of the string

Length = Len(Original_String)

'Set up the reversed string
Reversed_String = ""

'Progress through the string on a character by character basis
'Starting at the last character and going towards the first character

For Pos = Length To 1 Step -1

    Next_Char = Mid(Original_String, Pos, 1)
    Reversed_String = Reversed_String & Next_Char
Next Pos

MsgBox "The reversed string is " & Reversed_String

End Sub
```

Once you have the reversed string, do something like this:

LPosition = InStr(Reversed_String, ".")

That will find the period.  Then use the length of the string to find that period in the original string:

L2Position = len(mystring) - (len(mystring)-LPosition)

Then use your Mid function to find your state abbreviation.

Comment: There is an **InStrRev** function, no need to reverse your string first.

Answer (score 0):

based on your sample data you could use split

```
Dim vData
vData = Split(myString, ".")
myString = vData(ubound(vdata) - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

find periods (".") (and store the position of the last 2 found) until there are no more with a while looping Instr.

Now the state code is in between the last 2 found so apply: `mid(mystring,period1+1, period2-period1-1)`